# How do I fix React Native npm react-native init issue?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler, npm-init

I write npm react-native init newApp but it returns a problem in this form.I downloaded the metro package (npm i metro) but it didn't fix the problem.Could this problem be due to missing any packages?

```
Error: Cannot find module './Bundler/util'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\kamra\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\metro\src\Assets.js
- C:\Users\kamra\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js
- C:\Users\kamra\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\metro\src\shared\output\bundle.flow.js
- C:\Users\kamra\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\metro\src\shared\output\bundle.js
- C:\Users\kamra\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\build\commands\bundle\buildBundle.js
- C:\Users\kamra\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\build\commands\bundle\bundle.js
- C:\Users\kamra\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\build\commands\bundle\index.js
- C:\Users\kamra\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\build\commands\index.js
- C:\Users\kamra\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\build\index.js
- C:\Users\kamra\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\index.js
- C:\Users\kamra\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js
- C:\Users\kamra\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kamra\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\metro\src\Assets.js:14:32)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\kamra\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\Assets.js',
    'C:\\Users\\kamra\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\Server.js',
    'C:\\Users\\kamra\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\shared\\output\\bundle.flow.js',
    'C:\\Users\\kamra\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\shared\\output\\bundle.js',
    'C:\\Users\\kamra\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli-plugin-metro\\build\\commands\\bundle\\buildBundle.js',
    'C:\\Users\\kamra\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli-plugin-metro\\build\\commands\\bundle\\bundle.js',
    'C:\\Users\\kamra\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli-plugin-metro\\build\\commands\\bundle\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\kamra\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli-plugin-metro\\build\\commands\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\kamra\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli-plugin-metro\\build\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\kamra\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli\\build\\commands\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\kamra\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli\\build\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\kamra\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli\\build\\bin.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.13.0
```

Comment: Did you run `pod install`?

Comment: Did you mean to use `npx react-native init`?

Comment: @DreamBold No, but I used it and the problem was not solved

Comment: @S.V. Yes i use

Comment: To be clear, `npx` is different from `npm`. `npx` should not depend on your installed dependencies at all. If `npx react-native init foo` isn't working for you, you may have missed a step [from this guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup). Be sure to click "React native CLI Quickstart" tab.